# cake php redirects to blank page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

**Edit1:** when my directory is www/cake/cake2.1/app it works fine but when its www/cake/app i am facing the problem below.

Hi i have just started off with cake php was doing the blog tutorial. I am trying to create a form and store the values in db as per tutorial i followed all the steps.

The problem is the values are getting stored into Db but i am redirected into a blank page.

**controller:**

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index(){
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    function view($id = null) {        
        $this->Post->id = $id;        
        $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());    
    }
    function add(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the redirect is not happening properly it displays a blank page with url
hxxp://localhost/cake/posts/add

even tried    `$this->redirect('http://www.google.com');` doesn't work any help guys ?

post model:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: what happens when you try to redirect to another action, or when you call redirect (for testing) at begining of add function (without save)?

Comment: the redirect to index from the post view page works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Found: the zip extraction was not proper all i did was to extract the zip file again and ran my code and hurray... it worked well

Answer (score 3):

It might be due to white space in end of file

Please check your file if white space is there after '?>' tag it redirects it to blank page

or you can remove '?>'(closing php tag) to remove this problem.

Comment: i dont have a ?> (php closing tag) i am following the cake php tutorial.

Comment: have added post model too. kindly help

Comment: remove white-space before <?php (open tag) & after ?> (closing tag) on both controller & model

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors. You have two closing `}` at the end of your `add()` method. Remove one and it should be fine.

Also worth keeping an eye on the error log at `/app/tmp/log/error.log` which will alert you of errors like this.

Comment: i have double checked the '}' they are correct. didnt find anything in error log. :(

Comment: Well yes, the closing `}` is correct now you've edited your question and removed one!